# Raspberry Pi Bare Metal Allocator Unexpected Behavior

Tags: rust, raspberry-pi, allocation, bare-metal

I am working on a bare metal Rust program on my Raspberry Pi 3 and I am currently trying to implement a linked list allocator. The allocator itself is designed as follows, as an optional pointer to the first free node:

```
pub struct LinkedListAllocator {
    free_list: Option<&'static mut FreeBlock>
}

struct FreeBlock {
    size: usize,
    next: Option<&'static mut FreeBlock>
}
```

I want to be able to initialize it with a given starting point and size, as follows

```
    pub fn init(&mut self, start: usize, size: usize) {
        if size == 0 {
            panic!("Heap must have non-zero size");
        }
        //self.free(start, size);

        let block_ptr = start as *mut FreeBlock;

        unsafe {
            let mut val = FreeBlock::from_components(size, None);
            block_ptr.write_volatile(val);
            self.free_list = Some(&mut *block_ptr); 
        }
    }
```

However, when I run this, my raspberry pi quickly blinks the green light a single time and then turns the red light on. Although this is at the end of the boot sequence, none of the other steps happen.

If I delete the line

`self.free_list = Some(&mut *block_ptr);`
the boot sequence runs as expected.

If however, I write `self.free_list = None;` instead, the same error occurs, so I am starting to suspect that something is going wrong writing to the allocator struct.

Any insights into this would be appreciated.

Comment: Please post a reproducible example.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman would you like the entire project as it stands?

Comment: The example should also be minimal. So if the entire project is the most minimal example you can get that still demonstrates the issue, yes.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman that would probably be the minimum needed to get this to run on another system. Should I add that?

Comment: "&'static" how could this be static ? voted as closed without debugging information. It could be anything.

Comment: @Stargateur I have used the linker to block of the Heap so it is not used for anything else and set the stack pointer so it doesn't encroach. Either way, shouldn't the program still run fine until the point where I initialize the heap?